# $http post request breaks rest of angularjs code

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I just started learning Angularjs and I am facing a peculiar problem. If I get my `$http post` to work, the rest of my code doesn't, and the other way around- if everything else works my  `$http post` doesn't. Does it have to do with my controller? Should I use a factory?

angularjs file:

```
var app = angular.module('emailApp', []);           
app.controller('EmailController', function($scope, $http) {    
    $http({
      method: "post",
      url: "php.php",
      data: $.param($scope.composeEmail),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response.data;
    });

    $scope.isPopupVisible = false;
    $scope.isComposePopupVisible= false;
    $scope.composeEmail = {};
    $scope.activeTab = "inbox";
    $scope.sentEmails = [];

    $scope.sendEmail = function() {
      $scope.isComposePopupVisible = false;                 
      $scope.composeEmail.date = new Date();
      $scope.sentEmails.push($scope.composeEmail);
    };

    $scope.showComposePopup = function() {
       $scope.composeEmail = {};
       $scope.isComposePopupVisible = true;
    };

    $scope.showPopup = function(email) {
        $scope.isPopupVisible = true;
        $scope.selectedEmail = email;
    }; 

});
```

Comment: In your question yesterday, the POST used `Content-Type: application/json`. Today you are using content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Why did you switch?

Comment: Because with `Content-Type: application/json` I cannot access the data with $_POST in php

Comment: JSON is a better format. `$_POST` is the legacy method for old fashioned round-trip page-reload apps.

Comment: Show us the code you used to get the $http.post to work, and the code you used to get the rest to work and we can help, also details are needed for what you mean by work/not work we don't have the same context you do here